# How to make save first and find below with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm a beginner with nodejs and mongoose.

So i have a trouble like that:

After, create a schema, model and put the data to it and save, i want to find again.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var typePlantSchema = new Schema({
    namePlant:String,
    estimateDuration:Number,
    conditionPh:Number

});


var typePlantModels=  mongoose.model('typePlant',typePlantSchema);
var typePlantModel = new typePlantModels();
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/AeroDB', function (err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('connection error', err);
    } else {
        console.log('connection successful');
    }
});
typePlantModel.namePlant='tam';
typePlantModel.estimateDuration=10;
typePlantModel.conditionPh=7;
typePlantModel.save();

typePlantModels.find({namePlant:"tam"},function(err,docs){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {console.log(docs);}
});
```

But when i run my code first time, i can't get any found result. If run it one more time, i found 1 result (event 2 results). It means find function exceed before save function. I think it depends to the order of callback function. So could you have any solution make it work? of coure, not put the find function in the save function.
Please help me do it.

**Update more question**

Actually, I want to transfer it to databse API. It looks like that:

```
var typePlantModels=  mongoose.model('typePlant',typePlantSchema);
var typePlantModel = new typePlantModels();
typePlant.prototype=typePlantModel;
typePlant.prototype.findByName=function(name){
self=this;
typePlantModels.find({namePlant:self.namePlant},function(err,docs){
console.log(docs)}
}
module.exports=typePlant;
```

And i can put it on save function or use save().then. Please help me make it works.
Thank a lot

Comment: To add your custom methods you should use mongoose way which is before you call mongoose.model add typePlantSchema.methods.findByName = function () { // this keyword is the model so you can call this.find(..) here} and then simply export the model exports.typePlant = mongoose.model('typePlant', typePlantSchema);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `find()` function is running before `save()` is complete.

The solution is to use the callback function of `save()`.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var typePlantSchema = new Schema({
    namePlant:String,
    estimateDuration:Number,
    conditionPh:Number

});    

var typePlantModels=  mongoose.model('typePlant',typePlantSchema);
var typePlantModel = new typePlantModels();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/AeroDB', function (err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('connection error', err);
    } else {
        console.log('connection successful');
    }
});

typePlantModel.namePlant='tam';
typePlantModel.estimateDuration=10;
typePlantModel.conditionPh=7;

typePlantModel.save().then(function(){
  typePlantModels.find({namePlant:"tam"},function(err,docs){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {console.log(docs);}
  });
});
```

Read up: [`.save()` | Mongoose Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)

---

**Update 1:**

To make the function external, instead of making anonymous function in the callback, declare the function outside:

```
typePlantModel.save().then(findThis("something"));

function findThis(val){
  typePlantModels.find({namePlant:val},function(err,docs){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {console.log(docs);}
  });
}
```

Now you can use `findThis()` whenever you want.

Comment: I know this way. But i don't want do it. My logic is check after save. May be i do something code and find out. So i want to find exterior of save.  Actually, i try to write a database API, and some one can call find function to find what they want. But my find function alway execute after save. And In here, you can write save().then

Comment: @user3758586 You need to know that `.save()` is an asynchronous function. :)

Comment: I know save() is an asynchronous function. But could i make my find to the same, and run afer this.

Comment: @user3758586 I don't understand what you mean in your last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95005/discussion-between-user3758586-and-rahul-desai).

Comment: Could I chat with you a little,

Answer (score 0):

Because node is asynchronous, you will need to use the `find` in a callback of the save. Like so:

```
typePlantModel.save(function(){
    typePlantModels.find({namePlant:"tam"},function(err,docs){

    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(docs);
    }
});
```

To make this code much cleaner I suggest you read on [promises](http://howtonode.org/promises)

Comment: I know that way. But I'm trying to write an db API. And any one just call my find with some criteria. They can't care what happen interior, they don't know what is save, callback or anything. they just call my find function, my save func, and every thing work that it must do.